# Flash Drive Multiple Partition For Backup

Tags: partitioning, backup, usb-flash-drive, system-restore, windows-backup

I'm trying do to something (experiment), I have 64 Gb flash drive and I break it to 3 sections.

[image: flash]

The first will be for `Back up Files`

The second partition will be `Create Restore Point` (in case OS fails - Diagnose problem)

The third will be for `Restore Drive` (but seems failed, it will delete all partition)

[image: Recovery Drive]

The 2 are in `NTFS`, `FAT32` is what Recovery Drive Assigned.

Is this possible to do? To have a flash drive with multiple options for Backup?

Answer (score 2):

The windows tool will destroy everything on your USB drive. Try this:

- Make the recovery drive
- Download a partition manager such as EaseUS (Can be used without license)
- Resize your partition to the desired size and move it to the end of the usb drive space
- Create the reset of your partitions

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows tool to create the "Recovery Drive" appears to destroy all contents on your USB flash drive "Disk 3" as it prepares the USB drive.  Therefore you cannot preserve the partition layout you created before running the "Recovery Drive" tool; instead, you must alter the partitions *after* that tool has run.

1. Create recovery drive using the "Recovery Drive" tool
2. Shrink the partition of the recovery drive created by that tool
3. Create the two other backup partitions in the remaining free space

Note: If you need to preserve the current contents of any of the partitions of `Disk 3`, then you'll need to back them up elsewhere first.

Comment: Resizing and moving partitions is also an option, but 3rd party software or Linux will be necessary - Windows' _Disk Management_ doesn't support partition moving.